# Check if array contains numbers from other array

Tags: ruby, arrays, list

I have this code:

```
tickets = Array.new(10) {rand(99999)+1}

list = []
(list << '%05i' % (rand(99999)+1)).uniq! while list.length < 5
number1, number2, number3, number4, number5 = list
```

How can I check if any `ticket` has the winning number? There are five winning numbers, because each one has different prizes.

Comment: As it is, `list` contains strings and `tickets` contains strings.

Comment: What is a "winning number"? What is a "prize"? What does "one" refer to?

Comment: @sawa - for example, if array `tickets` consist `number1`, then the prize for that ticket is 40$, if `tickets` consist `number2`, then the prize for that ticket is 20$.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby's Array includes `&`:

> Set Intersection — Returns a new array containing elements common to the two arrays, excluding any duplicates. The order is preserved from the original array.
>
> It compares elements using their hash and eql? methods for efficiency.

```
ary1 = [1,2,3]
ary2 = [2,4,6]

ary1 & ary2 # => [2]
```

This works with any type of object:

```
ary1 = %w[a b c]
ary2 = %w[c d e]

ary1 & ary2 # => ["c"]
```

So, if you have a list of tickets, and a single winning ticket:

```
tickets = [1,2,3]
winning_ticket = [2]

tickets & winning_ticket # => [2]
```

Answer (score 1):

May be something like below :

```
[number1, number2, number3, number4, number5].find{|e| tickets.include? e }
```